# Ошибка "redeclared 'search' defined above without usage"

Tags: python-3.x, webbrowser

Занимаюсь разработкой мини-проекта для быстрой работы с браузером, и вышла ошибка "redeclared 'search' defined above without usage". PyCharm указывает на строчку:

```
search = input("")
```

Может кто подсказать, как её исправить? Полный код:

```
import webbrowser

cycle = True

while cycle:
    print('Ещё что-нибудь?' or 'Я вас слушаю' or 'Ваш запрос:')
    search = input("")
    if search == "yt" or "YT" or "Ютуб" or "ютуб":
        webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://youtube.com")
    elif search == "Твич" or "твич" or "Twitch" or "twitch":
        webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://twitch.tv")
    else:
        webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + search)
    search = ""
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if search == "yt" or "YT" or "Ютуб" or "ютуб":
```

Это условие всегда будет истинно (не пустая строка всегда истинна, or истинен если любое из условий истинно), другие ветки не сработают, а ниже вы присваиваете search уже другое значение, вот и получается, что строка с инпутом бесполезна.

Правильно условие записать можно так:

```
if search.lower() in ("yt", "ютуб"):
```

Ну и в другой ветке такая же проблема.

Answer (score 1):

```
import webbrowser

cycle = True

while cycle:
    print('Ещё что-нибудь?' or 'Я вас слушаю' or 'Ваш запрос:')
    search = input("")
    if search == "yt" or search == "YT" or search == "Ютуб" or search == "ютуб":
        webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://youtube.com")
    elif search == "Твич" or search == "твич" or search == "Twitch" or search == "twitch":
        webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://twitch.tv")
    else:
        webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + search)
    search = None
```

после `or` нужно полностью переписывать условие

до:`if search == "yt" or "YT" or "Ютуб" or "ютуб"`

после:`if search == "yt" or search == "YT" or search == "Ютуб" or search == "ютуб":`